Angular viewcontainerref Append child slow
I am creating a wrapper div by createElements.I am creating a instance of the dynamic component by viewContainerRef.I am trying to append this dynamically created component to wrapper so that I can show a tool tip of leaflet(by bindpopup).there is a lag in appending the child, the wrapper of bindtooltip opens even before the child is appended.is there a way to resolve this
I am creating a wrapper div by createElements.I am creating a instance of the dynamic component by viewContainerRef.I am trying to append this dynamically created component to wrapper so that I can show a tool tip of leaflet(by bindpopup).there is a lag in appending the child, the wrapper of bindtooltip opens even before the child is appended.is there a way to resolve this
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.className = 'tooltip';
let list= [{name:"john",type:"house"},{name:"vijay",type:"house"}];
arrComponents.map(val=>{
  let component = this.service.vcr.createComponent(dynamicComponent)
  component.instance.value= {

    label:name,
    value:type,
  }
  let componentObj= component.location.nativeElement
  wrapper.appendChild(componentObj)
})

please not that I am doing this inside a service,not inside a component,so I will not be able to use ElementRef

Instead of createElement go for createDocumentFragment which will give you a performance increase since

Creates a new empty DocumentFragment into which DOM nodes can be added to build an offscreen DOM tree.

The stackblitz demonstrates the usage of createDocumentFragment feel free to apply this logic based on your requirements.
    import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  inject,
  Renderer2,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ value.label }}: {{ value.value }}!</h1>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  value: any = {};
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  vcr = inject(ViewContainerRef);
  renderer = inject(Renderer2);
  element = inject(ElementRef);

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const wrapper = document.createDocumentFragment(); // changed here!
    // wrapper.className = 'tooltip';
    let list = [
      { name: 'john', type: 'house' },
      { name: 'vijay', type: 'house' },
    ];
    list.map((val) => {
      let component = this.vcr.createComponent(Child);
      component.instance.value = {
        label: val.name,
        value: val.type,
      };
      let componentObj = component.location.nativeElement;
      wrapper.appendChild(componentObj);
    });
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.element.nativeElement, wrapper);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
